# Python Pandas Create Multiple dataframes from list

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Using this as a quick starting point;

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
         date variable     value
0  2000-01-03        A  0.469112
1  2000-01-04        A -0.282863
2  2000-01-05        A -1.509059
3  2000-01-03        B -1.135632
4  2000-01-04        B  1.212112
5  2000-01-05        B -0.173215
6  2000-01-03        C  0.119209
7  2000-01-04        C -1.044236
8  2000-01-05        C -0.861849
9  2000-01-03        D -2.104569
10 2000-01-04        D -0.494929
11 2000-01-05        D  1.071804
```

Then isolating 'A' gives this:

```
In [2]: df[df['variable'] == 'A']
Out[2]: 
        date variable     value
0 2000-01-03        A  0.469112
1 2000-01-04        A -0.282863
2 2000-01-05        A -1.509059
```

Now creating new dataframe would be:

```
dfA = df[df['variable'] == 'A']
```

Lets say B's would be:

```
dfB = df[df['variable'] == 'B']
```

So, Isolating the dataframes into dfA, dfB, dfC......

```
dfList  = list(set(df['variable']))
dfNames = ["df" + row for row in dfList]  

for i, row in enumerate(dfList):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    dfNew = df[df['variable'] == row]
    dfNames[i] = dfNew
```

It runs... But when try `dfA` I get output `"dfA" is not defined`

Comment: You are writing `dfNew` into `dfNames[i]`, not `dfA`.  It's roughly equivalent to the difference between `dfA` and `"dfA"`.  I don't know if an exact solution to your question is possible in python due to the lack of macros.  You maybe could do this with a context manager? But really, I would think about doing it another way.  It might help if you could give some more context for the overall issue.

Comment: @JohnE Thanks, Its much harder than it looks. I am trying to create everything dynamically, Segment out the smaller arrays so I can pickle them. In the above example, Simply trying to find a way to break out those four categories into separate df or array.. thanks for actually reading the code.

Comment: @JohnE look at accepted ans.

Comment: yep, that is thorough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question literally, `globals()['dfA'] = dfNew` would define `dfA`
in the global namespace:

```
for i, row in enumerate(dfList):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    dfNew = df[df['variable'] == row]
    globals()[dfName] = dfNew
```

However, there is never a good reason to define dynamically-named variables.

- If the names are not known until runtime -- that is, if the names are *truly*
  dynamic -- then you you can't use the names in your code since your code has
  to be written before runtime. So what's the point of creating a variable named
  `dfA` if you can't refer to it in your code?
- If, on the other hand, you know before hand that you will have a variable
  named `dfA`, then your code isn't really dynamic. You have static variable names.
  The only reason to use the loop is to cut down on boiler-plate code. However,
  even in this case, there is a better alternative.
  The solution is to use a dict (see below) or list<sup>1</sup>.
- Adding dynamically-named variables pollutes the global namespace.
- It does not generalize well. If you had 100 dynamically named variables, how
  would you access them? [How would you loop over them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096621/190597)
- To "manage" dynamically named variables you would need to keep a list of their
  names as strings: e.g. `['dfA', 'dfB', 'dfC',...]` and then accessed the newly
  minted global variables via the `globals()` dict: e.g. `globals()['dfA']`. That
  is awkward.

So the conclusion programmers reach through bitter experience is that
dynamically-named variables are somewhere between awkward and useless and it is
much more pleasant, powerful, practical to store key/value pairs in a dict. The
name of the variable becomes a key in the dict, and the value of the variable
becomes the value associated with the key. So, instead of having a bare name `dfA`
you would have a dict `dfs` and you would access the `dfA` DataFrame via
`dfs['dfA']`:

```
dfs = dict()
for i, row in enumerate(dfList):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    dfNew = df[df['variable'] == row]
    dfs[dfName] = dfNew
```

or, as [Jianxun Li shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31927650/190597),

```
dfs = {k: g for k, g in df.groupby('variable')}
```

This is why Jon Clements and Jianxun Li answered your question by showing
alternatives to defining dynamically-named variables.  It's because we all
believe it is a terrible idea.

---

Using Jianxun Li's solution, to loop over [a dict's key/value pairs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) you could then use:

```
dfs = {k: g for k, g in df.groupby('variable')}
for key, df in dfs.items():
    ...
```

or using Jon Clements' solution, to [iterate through groups](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) you could use:

```
grouped = df.groupby('variable')
for key, df in grouped:
    ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If the names are numbered or ordered you could use a list instead of a dict.

Comment: using Jianxun Li answer your modification to his ans. How would loop over the dict and isolate the the 'k' into their own dataframe... I am trying to generalize a solution so I dont know the keys ahead of time. I can drop the "df" in 'dfA'

Comment: To loop over a dict, `dfs`, use `for key, values in dfs.items()` (in Python3), or `for key, values in dfs.iteritems()` (in Python2). I don't understand what "isolate the 'k' into their own dataframe" means. If your question is a clarification of the current question, please add it your question above. If it is a follow-up question, please consider asking it as a new question.

Comment: Isolate each key into its own dataframe.. So, there are 4 keys, then there would be 4 dataframes.

Comment: Then use the `for key, value in dfs.items()` loop as shown above.

Comment: Regarding your suggested edit: My answer was really an attempt to convince you
to not use `globals()`. Therefore I do not want to add `globals` there since I
am NOT advocating the use of `globals()`. Once you have the `dict` as in Jianxun
Li's answer, there is **no need for** using `globals()[key] = df`. Anywhere you would need `A`, you would use `dfs['A']` instead.

Comment: Fine, But I cant create 'A' as a stand alone dataframe using dfs['A'] and that is what I need..

Answer (score 5):

Use `groupby` and `get_group`, eg:

```
grouped = df.groupby('variable')
```

Then when you want to do something with each group, access it as such:

```
my_group = grouped.get_group('A')
```

Gives you:

```
    date    variable    value
0   2000-01-03  A   0.469112
1   2000-01-04  A   -0.282863
2   2000-01-05  A   -1.509059
```

Comment: does not really answer the question..  A list into multiple dataframes... Trying not to use groupby, trying to solve above question.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to create dynamically named variables and perform a linear scan of the original dataframe as many times as the number of unique values of `variables` + 1? @Merlin?

Answer (score 1):

`df.groupby('variable')` returns an iterator with `key/df` pairs. So to get a list/dict of subgroups,

```
result = {k: g for k, g in df.groupby('variable')}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)

{'A':          date variable   value
0  2000-01-03        A  0.4691
1  2000-01-04        A -0.2829
2  2000-01-05        A -1.5091,
 'B':          date variable   value
3  2000-01-03        B -1.1356
4  2000-01-04        B  1.2121
5  2000-01-05        B -0.1732,
 'C':          date variable   value
6  2000-01-03        C  0.1192
7  2000-01-04        C -1.0442
8  2000-01-05        C -0.8618,
 'D':           date variable   value
9   2000-01-03        D -2.1046
10  2000-01-04        D -0.4949
11  2000-01-05        D  1.0718}


result['A']

         date variable   value
0  2000-01-03        A  0.4691
1  2000-01-04        A -0.2829
2  2000-01-05        A -1.5091
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, row in enumerate(dfList):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    dfNew = df[df['variable'] == row]
    vars()[dfNames[i]] = dfNew
```

Comment: The vars() function will extract the values of dfName and turns them to variables

Comment: please, give an explanation to your answer

Comment: The output of the code above is " 'dfA' is not defined " , that's because he is trying to assign a dataframe to a string (which is 'dfA' ).  So to convert  strings to variables we need to use the vars() function. In this case for example dfNames[i] = "dfA", so when we apply vars()[dfNames[i]] will return a variable dfA .