# Create Multiple .csv from Single Dataframe by Filtering on Column value

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, split

Here is my dataframe -

```
     Date   |Val1| Val2|

 0   1/1/2015|   a|   2|
 1   1/1/2015|   g|   6|
 2   1/2/2015|   d|   4|
 3   1/2/2015|   a|   6|
 4   1/2/2015|   f|   7|
 5  1/13/2015|   b|   8|
 6  1/14/2015|   r|   0|
 7  1/14/2015|   a|   1|
 8  1/12015|     t|   2|
```

I want to take the value on the column 'Date' and create separate .csv as in 
01012015.csv,  01022015.csv,  01132015.csv,  01142015.csv etc.

And each of the .csv file would have the data only for those dates.
Ideally I was thinking of splitting the data frame into multiple dataframes and then create the .csv. 
However I can do them manually using  but not being able to do that using a loop or using unique() list.

I've looked at the below but it doesn't get to what I need.
[Python Pandas Create Multiple dataframes from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927309/python-pandas-create-multiple-dataframes-from-list)

Comment: Could you create a dataframe one can easily read in!?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're just looking for [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). If your dataframe is called `df`, and the "Date" column is a string, then something like below should work:

```
df_by_date = df.groupby("Date")
for (date, date_df) in df_by_date:
    filename = date.replace("/", "") + ".csv"
    date_df.to_csv(filename)
```